# Getting invalid arguments using .substr of String class in C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, string

I'm trying to test whether string input is legal via the following function in C++ using Eclipse:

```
#include <string>

bool testLegal::checkData(std::string &input, int &reg) {

    //test to see if pitchnames are legal

    std::string toneClasses = "CDEFGAB";
    std::string accidentals = "#b";
    std::string toTest;

    try {
        //TEST 1 IS the pitch name legal?
        toTest = input.substr(0, 1);
        if (_isLegal(toTest, toneClasses) == false)
            throw dataClean(2, "The pitch name you entered is illegal. Please correct it!");

        //TEST 2 to see if there is a second character in the pitch name and whether it is a sharp or flat
        toTest = input.substr(1);
        if (input.length() == 2 && _isLegal(toTest, accidentals) == false)
            throw dataClean(3, "The second character in the pitch name must be a sharp or flat");

    } catch (const cExceptions& e) {    
        throw dataClean(4, "There is an error in the data you inputed. Please re-enter");
    }
    return true;
}
```

However I'm getting an 'Invalid Argument' error with regard to the parameters of .substr. I've tried various solutions without success. Curiously, the function runs without any problems in both Netbeans and Codelite. I would be grateful for any ideas is to how to solve this. Thx in anticipation...

Comment: How are you getting an invalid argument error, on the console? What is the input string that you are testing?

Comment: Seems fine, the code. Is this all of the code?

Comment: The input is in the form of a musical pitch name eg 'A#'. I'm getting an error even before I build. Also im having a similar problem with another function of the same class:

Comment: I have the same .substr problem in another function in the same class:

Comment: I am not sure how you get an error before you build? Can you do a build and paste the error message here?

Comment: Does the code compile ok? It might be just due to Eclipse CDE's code analysis module, which occasionally sees errors where there aren't any. Try to upgrade to the latest version of Eclipse (if you haven't done already), and deactivate the offending options in the code analysis settings (I had to do the same).

Comment: I have the same problem. The code compiles fine. The problem is that Eclipse cannot resolve parameters for substr() function. If you hover over it, it shows that the declaration is substr(?,?). It looks like a bug in Eclipse or something needs to be set up properly.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem on Eclipse with substrings when using NDK. I had to cast the integers to **string::size_type**

```
string twoLetters = hexStr.substr((string::size_type)i,(string::size_type)2);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any check verifying that your input contains sufficient characters: trying to get a substring which exceeds the size of the string can create the error your quoted. Similarly, starting at an invalid index may cause this problem, too. That is, I'd guess you `input` actually happens to be empty. Try adding:

```
if (input.empty()) {
    throw std::runtime_error("received an empty string");
}
```

Comment: THx Dietmar. Your right the possibility of input string being empty should be covered. However doesn't get away from the "Invalid Argument" for .substr issue. I note that despite a 'bug' icon appearing at those lines containing substr the code now builds OK. is this really a 'bug' in Eclipse I wonder?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed it for Eclipse CDT. Open the Properties and go into Paths and Symbols section. If rest of C++ code is working fine, you probably have some kind of line to include C++ header files. For example, on my Mac it's this:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
```

Now, add a new entry that includes "tr" subdirectory as well:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/tr
```

Rebuild the index afterwards and you're done.